# Geo location that should show the current location of user

Tags: javascript, async-await

the data is fetching in the console but I need it to be in the response please help me with that

```
    const getLoc = async () => {
    if (latitude !== "" && longitude !== "") {
        console.log("call google api");
        let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key={key}`;
        await axios(url, {
            method: "get",
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("res", res);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: Your async function isn’t returning anything. Also, pick one: then vs await/async.

Comment: I'm not  getting can u please send a code to return please